# How to join table with 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I want to join 2 columns base on this :
A.Contactnumber and the 2 column B.old_contact, B.recent_contact

I want to retain the old contact and at the same time include recent if they're not alike

```
select a.*, b.old_contact, b.recent_contact
from table a
left join table b
on a.contactnumber = b.old_contact
```

Comment: 2 separate independent columns needs in joining 2 separate independent table `a` copies. And `LEFT` joining makes no sense in your case (or at least use backward tables joining order).

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT a.contactnumber, b.old_contact, b.recent_contact
    FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.contactnumber=b.old_contact 
    WHERE b.old_contact!=b.recent_contact;
```

as the result you will get the values which are present in table "a" and in table "b" and which have different values in columns "old_contact" and "recent_contact" in table "b". Is that what you need?